# Put textarea resize handle at the top

Tags: html, css

My layout looks approximately like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cburschka/bcnvzsrt/

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="input">
    <textarea id="inputField"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: auto;
}
#messages { 
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#sidebar {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#inputField {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

The main content is a vertical flexbox, with the central pane filling the available space while the text area below it has a fixed size.

I want to make this textarea vertically resizable.

As shown in the example, this technically works, but the interface is deeply counter-intuitive. Even though the textarea grows *upward* (because that's how the flexbox is laid out), I have to use a handle in the bottom right corner and drag it *downward* to make it grow.

Is there any chance of placing the resize handle on the top edge of the textarea instead? (Preferably without extra libraries and JS, but I'm not too optimistic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I found a solution using jQuery UI. It's not quite straightforward, and involves a CSS hack.

Using it out of the box will not work in this case, as testable with this snippet:

```
$(inputField).resizable({handles: 'n'});
```

While this will put a draggable resize handle at the top, jQuery UI will simultaneously attempt to reposition the textarea using `position: relative`, in order to keep its bottom edge in place as it grows.

Because the flexbox model already keeps the textarea's bottom edge in position, this is redundant. jQuery UI will cause the whole textarea to move upward at the same rate as it is growing.

While there doesn't seem to be a way to tell jQuery to skip the repositioning, I fixed it by adding `top: 0!important` to the CSS.